# App crash after canceling search for bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making a game over bluetooth. When the joining player cancels the searching for device dialog the app crashes. I don't know how to stop this error.

Here my activity which starts the searching for device:(code sample)
MainBluetoothActivity.java:

```
public void onCreateClicked(View view) {
        
        Intent discoverableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        
        startActivityForResult(discoverableBtIntent, REQ_DISCOVERABILITY_BT);
        
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(this);
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
    
    public BluetoothAdapter getBluetoothAdapter() {
        return mBluetoothAdapter;
    }
    
    public void onJoinClicked(View view) {
        
        Intent deviceListIntent = new Intent( this, DeviceListActivity.class );
        startActivityForResult( deviceListIntent, REQ_DEVICE_LIST );
        
    }
    
    
    private void ErrorMsg(String title, String msg) {
    
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        
        switch(requestCode) {
        
        case REQ_ENABLE_BT:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                ErrorMsg("Bluetooth Enable", "Bluetooth is obligatory, press OK to close app");
            break;
        case REQ_DISCOVERABILITY_BT:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                ErrorMsg("Bluetooth Enable", "Bluetooth is obligatory, press OK to close app");
            else {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.waiting);
            tv.setText(R.string.waitingLabel);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btAdapterName);
            tv.setText( "Your Name:\n" + mBluetoothAdapter.getName() );
            tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.btAdapterMAC );
            tv.setText( "Your MAC:\n" + mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress() );
            
            Button button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.createButton );
            button.setEnabled( false );
            button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.joinButton );
            button.setEnabled( false );
            
            
            }
            
            break;
        case REQ_DEVICE_LIST:
            
            String macAddress = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
            
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.joinButton);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connecting);
            tv.setText(R.string.connectingLabel);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectingTo);
            tv.setText("Remote Device Name:\n" + device.getName() + "Remote Device MAC:\n" + device.getAddress());
            
            if(mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
            
            mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, this);
            mConnectThread.start();
            
            
            
            break;

        default:
            ErrorMsg("Request Code", "Request Code is unknown");
            break;
            
        }
    }
```

Here is the class which searches for bluetooth phones:

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Return Intent extra
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the window
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

        // Set result CANCELED incase the user backs out
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
        // one for newly discovered devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Get a set of currently paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }
    }
    

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        // Set result CANCELED incase the user backs out
    }

    /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setTitle(R.string.scanning);

        // Turn on sub-title for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

            // Set result and finish this Activity
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    // The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
    // changes the title when discovery is finished
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

and the error-message:

```
12-12 13:08:18.246: W/dalvikvm(20435): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4190aba8)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435): Process: com.example.calma, PID: 20435
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.calma/com.example.calma.MainBluetoothActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at com.example.calma.MainBluetoothActivity.onActivityResult(MainBluetoothActivity.java:101)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
12-12 13:08:18.256: E/AndroidRuntime(20435):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You should check if resultCode is not null. Like if(resultCode!=null){ switch(resultCode){}...do the switch stuff }. also the request code must be checked if not null...

Comment: thank you that helped i implemented that and now the problem is solved.